# How do you disable a text area using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I cannot seem to get this basic jQuery script to work. I thought I could do it but apparently I am fairly uninformed in what is going. I am using Rails 4.

When creating a new report I want to be able to disable the report body when document loads. In the long run I want to disable the report body until the first two field forms are filled out. I don't think the jQuery is getting through at all. I tried a basic `.hide()` function and it didn't work. I have jQuery working in other portions of my app. Thanks for your time!

new.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#report_body").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@report, remote: true) do |f| %>
    ... snippet ...
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <%= f.input :body, input_html: { rows: 20, style: 'width: 100%;', id: 'report_body' }%>
    </div>
    ... snippet ... 
<% end %>
```

reports controller

```
  # GET /reports/new
   def new
    @report = Report.new
    # I tried doing a respond to block here for format.js but I think thats only for AJAX callbacks?
   end
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: The best way to hide something at load time is via CSS: `#report_body { display: none; }` You can never go wrong with that.

Comment: @pyRabbit try using attr instead of prop, and just use disabled no need to set it true.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone! @adnan, thanks for the suggestion, I gave it a shot but it didn't seem to work for me. It makes me wonder if the jQuery is even getting to my page

Comment: @pyRabbit if it always needs to disabled by default then add "disabled" in html instead of adding it dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should do is check to see if JQuery can find your DOM element.

Try debugging via console to see if the element can be found with the criteria you're giving. This always helps when trying to isolate DOM elements.

```
console.debug($("#report_body").contents());
```

I'm not sure if you have other elements with the same ID beyond the snippet you gave, but if you do, it would be better practice to make report_body a class name instead.

Assuming all those are in check, you may want to try the following:

```
$('input#report_body').attr('disabled', true);
```

If there are multiple instances of text areas sharing the same class name,

```
    $(this).find('input.report_body').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
```

Alternatively, you can also have the field disabled by default in Ruby using:

```
 <%= f.input :body, :disabled => true, input_html: {...}%>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got it to work being more specific like your example in the second code snippet.